# How to update EF entity, when passing modified entity as a parameter?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a quick question.

Assuming that **context** is my EF Context, and **Respondent** is actual EF Entity generated by EF from the database.

What is the shortest way to update the **Respondent**?

```
public void UpdateRespondent(Respondent respondent)
{
    var resp = context.Respondents.First(r => r.RespondentId == respondent.RespondentId);

    // Now... do I have to copy all properties from the respondent into resp ??
    // But respondent is actually the Respondent entity
    // Can I just replace it somehow?

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks a bunch.

**Update1**

Thanks to nrodic, this code works like a charm:

```
public void UpdateRespondent(Respondent changed)
{
    var respondent = db.Respondents.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RespondentId == changed.RespondentId);

    db.Respondents.ApplyCurrentValues(changed);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

One question though - **looks like I dont need the first line** "var respondent = " at all !!

Any idea why in many examples this line is present?

Thanks.

**Update2**

Hmm, looks like I need that first line.
Otherwise it throws exception on the second line (db.Respondents.ApplyCurrentValues(changed);)

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) or [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but why would I need some 3rd party libs?
Both are the same entity. Respondent IS actual EF entity, it is not a VewModel or any custom thing. It is EF Entity for a DB table. I thought straight one line code replacement can do the update.

Comment: Is there a direct EF injection, since resp and respondent is the same thing.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2453247/551322) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1438833/551322) can help.

Comment: Thanks @nrodic, exactly what I was looking for.
Please see updated code above.
My only question - do I even need the first line ??? (finding the respondent in the database) - it is not even used.

Comment: Looks like I need it :) please see updated post

Comment: You need to attach/add the object first then apply changes if you're going to do it that way.

Comment: Loading entity into context actually makes sense because EF takes care for integrity of loaded entities. By the way, do you have navigation properties in updated entity and did you check if they are updated?

Comment: Navigation properties, you mean to the parent entity that contains multiple Respondents. No, I dont have these, but for 1 respondent I have multiple... "items" from another table. But I dont think they are affected in any way. From what I understand EF uses EntityKey to match the entity instances, but the key itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
    public void UpdateRespondent(Respondent respondent)
{
    var resp = context.Respondents.First(r => r.RespondentId == respondentId);

    // Now... do I have to copy all properties from the respondent into resp ??
    // But respondent is actually the Respondent entity
    // Can I just replace it somehow?

    resp.Name = "Bob";
    resp.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can just update the properties on the resp object. Although seeing the first comment it might not be exactly what you are after.

Comment: yes, I know that, that's why I wrote in the post "Now... do I have to copy all properties from the respondent into resp ??"

I am looking for an easier option, what if I have 50 fields ?? :)

Comment: Can I just replace the resp with respondent, or just straight copy one into another?

Comment: The comment below your question may help you further. Sorry this wasn't that helpful!

Comment: Sorry, missed that :) True, there must be a simple way to do this. I have heard that there is some Attach / Detach functionality in EF...

Answer (score 0):

If you load entity, detach it from the context and update its properties, you can apply changes to database with method [`ApplyCurrentValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx). Use it like this:

```
public void UpdateRespondent(Respondent changed)
{
    var respondent = db.Respondents.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RespondentId == changed.RespondentId);

    db.Respondents.ApplyCurrentValues(changed);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that entity must be attached to the context (read from database) when calling `ApplyCurrentValues()`. Otherwise `InvalidOperationException` would be thrown:

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

If you use `DbContext` instead of `ObjectContext`, make sure to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5807622/551322).

---

Another way to update database could be to use technique of automatic mapping ([Automapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) for example). This is more general case because it allows the use of DTO and provides good control over what is (and how) to be updated.